# how to simplify the way to delete blank string in a list?

Tags: python, list

```
x=["x1",""," ","   ","y1"]
y=[]
import re
for id in range(0,5):
    if(not re.findall("^\s*$",x[id])): y.append(x[id])

y
["x1","y1"]
```

I can delete blank string in a list in python,it feels complicated,how can i simplify my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use list comprehension based filtering, like this

```
print [current_string for current_string in x if current_string.strip() != ""]
# ['x1', 'y1']
```

In Python, [an empty string is considered as Falsy](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing). So, the same can be written succinctly like this

```
print [current_string for current_string in x if current_string.strip()]
```

Apart from that, you can use the [`filter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) function, to filter out the empty strings like this

```
stripper, x = str.strip, ["x1",""," ","   ","y1"]
print filter(stripper, x)
```

Answer (score 2):

[list comprehension](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/lists/list-comprehensions-in-python/) with if statement:

```
y = [i for i in x if i.strip()]
#['x1', 'y1']
```

Answer (score 2):

```
y = filter(lambda i: i.strip(), x)
#['x1', 'y1']
```

or more succinct version by @Jiri

```
filter(str.strip, x)
```

Comment: filter(string.strip,x) is better

Comment: to @Jiri Great point. Fix the typo for you: `filter(str.strip, x)`

Comment: That was not a typo - I assumed using string module (`import string`). But your usage of str is better :) you do not need that import than.

Comment: One more think regarding unicode strings: I think you should remove str.strip version from answer - we should prefer variant with import string, because string.strip function handles unicode flawlessly but str.strip version throws exception when element in list is unicode. Your version works with unicode too.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> o = ['','1']
>>> n = []
>>> for each in o:
     if each.strip():
        n.append(each)
>>> n
['1']
>>>
```